# Functions to draw shapes

Tags: python, function, drawing

The main function in your program should be named: drawShape().

o The main function will prompt for two values namely the width and the 
height. Assume that:

 both values will be 2 or greater (no error checking required)

 the second input (height) will be even

o The shape created will always be as wide as the user indicates.

o The total shape height will be one row larger than the user indicates.

o Regardless of what the height is, half of the shape will be printed above a line 
of plus signs and the other half will be printed below the line.

```
def drawShape():              
   width = int(input("Please enter the shape width: "))                
   height = int(input("Please enter the shape height: "))                       
   print("#")
   for i in range(width, height):
      print("#")
      print("+")
   return
```

Expected Ouput:

```
drawShape()
Please enter the shape width: 4 
Please enter the shape height: 2


####
++++
####
```

My obtained ouput:

```
drawShape()
Please enter the shape width: 3
Please enter the shape height: 6
#
#
+
#
+
#
+
```

I am having trouble getting it to print the correct width and height. Can someone please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Using `'#'*width` to generate a string of `'#'` with expected width.
2. `range(width, height)` does not make sense, just `range(height)` (or `height/2` in your case).

Then you can make it like this:

```
In [368]: print('#'*width)
     ...: for i in range(height/2):
     ...:     print('+'*width)
     ...:     print('#'*width)
###
+++
###
+++
###
+++
###
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, would this code work for a width of 2 and height of 4. I need it to work for all values (is there a particular expression i need to enter for this to happen?)

Comment: @user3321010 well, that's your job then, try it out yourself ;)